# Reverse Indexing in Python?

Tags: python

I know that **a[end:start:-1]** slices a list in a reverse order.

**For example**

```
a = range(20)
print a[15:10:-1] # prints [15, ..., 11]
print a[15:0:-1] # prints [15, ..., 1]
```

but you cannot get to the first element (0 in the example). It seems that -1 is a special value.

```
print a[15:-1:-1] # prints []
```

Any ideas?

Comment: [The Python Slice Notation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation)

Comment: This could also be interesting for you: `print(list(reversed(range(5))))`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can assign your variable to `None`:

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> a[15:None:-1]
[15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
>>>
```

Comment: This (using `None`) is probably the best solution, but note that you can also use negative indices all the way around: `a[-5:-21:-1]` gets you the same slice, including the final `a[0]` element.

Comment: @torek I also thought of using negative indices, but I think that is the best solution, because you can avoid the extra assignment to `None` (see my answer).

Answer (score 15):

Omit the end index:

```
print a[15::-1]
```

Comment: start and end are actually variables.

Comment: do I need a special if statement for this?

Comment: you can do it without an if statement if you don't mind doing this in two steps: `print a[low:high+1][::-1]`

Comment: @MohammadMoghimi You can use `None`.

Comment: My list is very long. I think this slices the list first and then reverses it.

Comment: Well, I guess you can go with an if statement: `print a[high:low-1:-1] if low>0 else a[high::-1]`

Answer (score 8):

In Python2.x, the simplest solution in terms of number of characters should probably be :

```
>>> a=range(20)

>>> a[::-1]
[19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Though i want to point out that if using xrange(), indexing won't work because xrange() gives you an xrange object instead of a list.

```
>>> a=xrange(20)
>>> a[::-1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence index must be integer, not 'slice'
```

After in Python3.x, range() does what xrange() does in Python2.x but also has an improvement accepting indexing change upon the object.

```
>>> a = range(20)
>>> a[::-1]
range(19, -1, -1)
>>> b=a[::-1]
>>> for i in b:
...     print (i)
... 
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
>>>
```

the difference between range() and xrange() learned from source: http://pythoncentral.io/how-to-use-pythons-xrange-and-range/
by author: Joey Payne

Comment: Wut? Is this an answer?

Comment: My direct answer is just a[::-1]. The following part is some possible complications people may find if they are using different version of python. Sorry about the confusion. I am new here, do you think i should delete the non-direct answer part and where should i put it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
>>> print a[:6:-1]
[19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7]
>>> a[7] == a[:6:-1][-1]
True
>>> a[1] == a[:0:-1][-1]
True
```

So as you can see when subsitute a value in start label :end: it will give you from start to end exclusively a[end].

As you can see in here as well:

```
>>> a[0:2:]
[0, 1]
```

---

**-1 is the last value in a:**

```
>>> a[len(a)-1] == a[-1]
True
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use negative indexes you can avoid extra assignments, using only your start and end variables:

```
a = range(20)
start = 20
for end in range(21):
    a[start:-(len(a)+1-end):-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: begin and end are variables

I never realized this, but a (slightly hacky) solution would be:

```
>>> a = range(5)
>>> s = 0
>>> e = 3
>>> b = a[s:e]
>>> b.reverse()
>>> print b
[2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: start and end are variables